# Qt Button with Id

Tags: c++, qt

I wanted an extended button which holds an int as Id and can signal it out:

Header:

```
#ifndef QPUSHBUTTONWITHID_H
#define QPUSHBUTTONWITHID_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMessageBox>

class QPushButtonWithId : public QPushButton
{
public:
    QPushButtonWithId(int id);
    void setId(int id);

protected:
    int Id;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);


signals:
    void clicked(int);
};

#endif // QPUSHBUTTONWITHID_H
```

Cpp:

```
#include "qpushbuttonwithid.h"

QPushButtonWithId::QPushButtonWithId(int id)
{
    Id = id;
}

void QPushButtonWithId::setId(int id)
{
    Id = id;
}

void QPushButtonWithId::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    emit clicked(Id);
}
```

The compile error is:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.2.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\untitled\qpushbuttonwithid.cpp:15: error: undefined  reference to `QPushButtonWithId::clicked(int)'
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You forgot to include Q_OBJECT macro in your class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot Q_OBJECT declaration:

```
class QPushButtonWithId : public QPushButton
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of subclassing the button, you can also use the [property system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/properties.html#reading-and-writing-properties-with-the-meta-object-system).

```
// Set a property
ui->button->setProperty("myId", 1);

// Get the property in the slot
void mySlot() {
  QVariant propertyV = sender()->property("myId");
  if (propertyV.isValid()) {
    int property = propertyV.toInt();
    ...
  }
}
```